# solidity v0.8.15 : require & mapping issues on ETH mainnet

Tags: deployment, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, evm

I'm working on a NFT management contrat; I can see everything works fine on rinkeby testnet, but when I'm calling the same functions on mainnet, I get errors many false errors with require. code was compiled on REMIX Ide;

Here is an example:

```
mapping(address => mapping(uint => uint8) public handledNfts;

mapping(bytes32 => uint8) public usedHashes;

function create(address contractAddress, uint tokenId, bytes32 hash) external
{
    uint8 vCheck = usedHashes[hash];

    require(vCheck!=1, "Bad hash");    // sometimes it has false-positive

    usedHashes[ hash ] = 1;

    uint8 vCheck = handledNfts[contractAddress][tokenId];
    
    require(vCheck!=1, "Already created");    // False-positive sometimes also

    handledNfts[contractAddress][tokenId] = 1;



    //--- DO SOMETHING ....
}
```

So when I'm on rinkeby any call to create will work.
However on mainnet, the create function returns a "Bad hash" or "Already closed" for no real reason, but sometimes in works like a charm.

So I don't know what's the problem on mainnet for a code which works fine from testnet?

It's strange because the
handledNfts[contractAddress][tokenId] should not be at ==1 when starting using the contrat.
However solidity says the hash has already been used or the nft says to be already managed, when it's not true.
Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Most of the time it doesn't

The hash using in the create function is always unique for each call.

Can someone help me find a solution on that instability, please?
It seems like mapping objects with a require don't work properly with me.

I compile the code through remix directly, with solidity v0.8.15
https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=true&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.15+commit.e14f2714.js

stangely also, I'm forced to use a variable to access a mapping object then use that variable; so a code like this is buggy on me many time:

```
require(usedHashes[hash]!=1, "Hash already used"); <-- buggy on mainnet
```

Any help please?

Comment: I will try ===> 
    if (usedHashes[hash]==1)  revert("Hash already used"); <====
Is it because my contract uses nearly 25400 bytes out of 25476 compiler limit. So nearly 99.99% of the space. And optimization is enabled to a value of 200

Comment: usedHashes[hash] is ZERO by default, so I don't understand why it is detected as ==1 by require, since I set usedHash to =1 after the require has passed.
On rinkeby and binance: NO problem. The problem only occur on Ethereum mainnet, I don't get this issue. It's only on mainnet. Any idea? because I called the function once.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what happened. I've been front-runned by a MEV BOT. It detected  an ETH transaction was sent from my smartcontract, and sent a copy-cat of the transaction earlier than mine.

I've put counter-actions to avoid it. it's okay now.